# Obter espaço em branco de uma string

Tags: delphi

Estou à procura de algo assim:

Tenho uma string assim:

```
      texto
           texto
  texto
                 texto
```

tipo, com espaços antes do texto, e eu preciso pegar este espaço, e guardar em uma variável, isso usando o Delphi 7. Só que o texto nem sempre é texto, pode ser `123`, pode ser outra palavra, mas preciso guardar o tamanho do espaço, por que vou precisar dele depois.

Alguma sugestão? Tentei `pos/copy`, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O meu Pascal já está muito esquecido mas julgo que pode fazer qualquer coisa do género:

```
Var S : String;

S:=StringOfChar(' ',Length(ASuaVariavel) - Length(TrimLeft(AsuaVariavel));
```

**Edit após o seu comentário**

Na pergunta, você diz que as strings têm espaços no início, no comentário refere que são *Tabs*, nesse caso o código necessita de ser alterado.

```
var
  suaString : string;
  TAB : char;
  tabCount : Integer;
  stringOfTabs : string;
begin

  TAB := #9;
  suaString:= TAB + TAB + TAB + 'Texto';
  tabCount := Length(suaString) - Length(TrimLeft(suaString));
  stringOfTabs := StringOfChar(TAB,tabCount);

  writeln('A sua string: ', suaString);
  writeln('Numero de Tabs: ', tabCount);
  writeln(stringOfTabs + 'Tabs aplicados a outra string');

end.
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/oCa0cq)

Comment: Obrigado. Vou tentar amanhã no meu trabalho, e dou-lhe um retorno. Pelo que li, a função StringOfChar é usada para pegar pequenos pedaços de uma string e converter em char, algo assim. Detalhe que estes espaços são tabulações, então podem ter 1, 2 ou mais tabulações, independente disso, tenho que saber quantas são, pois vou precisar concatenar isso com outra string depois.

Comment: ramaral, fiz aqui e deu certo. Ao invés de usar a StringOfChar, usei a função DupeString, ficou bom. Mas usei espaços, ao invés de tab, pois estava ficando muito fora a identação. Ah, esqueci de falar, isto é para um identador de código sql que estamos fazendo para incorporar dentro de nosso ERP. Muito obrigado pela sua atenção :)